# Show Image on div hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

There are many plugins where the caption of the image appears on hovering over the image (eg.:http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index4.html).

I want to achieve the opposite effect, i.e when one hovers on the div containing text, the image should appear. Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: As per guidelines please show some example code that you have used to generate this.
The solution is pretty simple, using either JS or Jquery, in general you will register an on hover event that acts however you want. If you have an example I would be glad to help more.

Comment: please show the code which you have tried...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what kind of animation you'r expecting. 
You can try something like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}
.container:hover .text {
  opacity: 0
}
.container:hover .img {
  opacity: 1
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
}
.img {
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    Hover On me....
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg" height='100%' width='100%' />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tt3oycty/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `html5`, and if so, you should use the tags appropriated for your content's context:

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" />
    <figcaption>Test message</figcaption>
</figure>
```

and the css

```
figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

figcaption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

figure:hover img {
    opacity: .7;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
    display: block;
}
```